# Sharepoint 2019 On-Premise Server Farm Broken (Blank White Screen)

Tags: sharepoint-2019

I have updated my Sharepoint 2019 Server Farms today ([KB5001975](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-july-13-2021-kb5001975-d67f177c-e493-4813-ab1e-799cb09897e6)), and after the update the documents and site content pages are shows only blank screen,

- `Home.aspx` - working,
- `/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx` - Not working (blank white screen)
- `/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx` - Not working (blank white screen)
- `/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx` - Not working (blank white screen)
- `/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx` - Not working (blank white screen)

  $farm = Get-SPFarm
  $farm.BuildVersion

  Major - 16
  Minor - 0
  Build - 10376
  Revision - 20001

i have restarted multiple times all the servers (Database server, application search server, central admin server, external facing server) still it shows blank white screen,

Also there is no error and warnings on the upgrade status (/_admin/UpgradeStatus.aspx), still i could not see any content on the site content pages

can i uninstall the updates which is installed recently?

Comment: Similar issue , looks like there is a issue with the Microsoft Security Patch Kb5001975 [Link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/problems-displaying-site-content/m-p/2552967)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed by installing the patch KB5001974 need to be installed along with the KB5001975

Answer (score 5):

This happened after install sharepoint 2019 updates. Installing patch KB5001974 worked for me

Comment: for some reason I cannot edit your comment, so just let the link to the patch: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103282

Comment: I had KB5002028 installed automatically, not KB5001975, and this fix still worked.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same - fresh ‘19 install with all Sharepoint updates available through WU - was getting the same blank screens on document lists and content lists.

KB5001974 which is a manual update solved this. The issue doesn’t appear in the list of included fixes for …974 or …975 but seems to have done the trick anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling modern view worked for me
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/how-to-disable-the-modern-experience-in-sharepoint-2019/ba-p/303649 as a work-around.

In my case I added an out of the box feature at Sitecollection level.

```
#Site Collection Level
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0
$site = Get-SPSite http://spwfe

#Disable modern Lists and libraries at the Site Collection Level
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true)

#Re-enable the modern experience at the site collection Level.
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
$site.Features.Remove($featureguid, $true)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29423233)

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto changed the original answer, you are right, its not linked only now.